# Space time nearest neighbor

Tags: python, proximity, time, nearest-neighbor

I have a dataset with 3 coordinates time, latitude and longitude.

How can I compute the nearest neighbor point for each point in the dataset using the 3 coordinates?

I'm using Python but I can't figure out a way to overcome this situation.

Comment: what format is your data in? How many points do you have? Are you using any specific python libraries?

Comment: I tried using BallTree from sklearn, the data is a list with 4000 points, each point is an event (time and space)

Comment: The problem is that BallTree considers the spatial distance but I need also to consider the temporal distance (all at once)

Comment: The data is organized in a pandas dataframe

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

How do you relate the distance in time to the distance in space? Are two points at the same location 1 day apart the same "distance" as two points at the same time 1km apart? Or 3km apart? This is called defining the "distance metric". Its a function that takes the differences in coordinates between two space-time points (`delta_x`, `delta_y`, `delta_t`) and returns a distance. In 2d planar its `sqrt(delta_x^2 + delta_y^2)`, but with time it could be anything within reason.

Unless you have an a-priori reason for choosing a speed to relate distance and time (for example, in cosmology, the speed of light is used for the distance-metric) then you can choose it arbitrarily or somehow driven by the data.

Comment: Each row is an event (a measurement) then the events occurs in some instant of time but also in a point in space, what I need is to compute the distance between points but considering also the time, two nearest points are close in space but also in time.

Comment: Yes, as I said *you* have to decide how to combine time distance and space distance. Maybe 1 day = 1km, in which case you scale your times so 1 day = 1000 metres and then do 3d pythagoras with x,y,t all in metres.

Comment: That is an interesting point of view, deal with time as an spatial coordinate, I will try!